# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core

I have a `tikz` graph of 484 nodes, about twice as many edges. As the error suggests, I am hitting some limit, but I am not sure which.

A graph of about 250 nodes renders fine. To add to my confusion, I think I was able to compile a similar tikz graph of 800 nodes earlier today. The topology and the depth were similar.

Here is the error message:
`TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]`

Edit: here is an example to reproduce the error. Following David's comment, I made it very simple - just a string of nested nodes to maximum depth (no branching). Curiously, it errors with 101 nodes. Remove one level of nesting - and it compiles.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\date{2023}


\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, svg.path, fit, positioning, matrix}
\tikzset{%
  >={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]},
  % Specifications for style of nodes:
  base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners=0.5mm, draw=black,
    minimum width=10mm, minimum height=4mm,
    text centered},
  process/.style = {base},
  outerbox/.style={rectangle, draw=black, dashed}
  task/.style = {base, circle}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
    
\framesubtitle{}

\tikz [>=stealth, black!50, text=black, very thin,
    every new ->/.style = {shorten >=1pt},
    graphs/every graph/.style = {edges=rounded corners},
    hv path/.style = {to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
    vh path/.style = {to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
    t/.style = {circle, minimum size=1mm, thin, draw=black!70, scale=0.1, fill=black!70},
    tl/.style = {circle, minimum size=1mm, thin, draw=blue!60, scale=0.1, fill=blue!60}
    ]
\graph [grow left sep=.7mm, branch down=.3mm, simple] {
0 / ""[t] -- {
1 / ""[t] -- {
2 / ""[t] -- {
3 / ""[t] -- {
4 / ""[t] -- {
5 / ""[t] -- {
6 / ""[t] -- {
7 / ""[t] -- {
8 / ""[t] -- {
9 / ""[t] -- {
10 / ""[t] -- {
11 / ""[t] -- {
12 / ""[t] -- {
13 / ""[t] -- {
14 / ""[t] -- {
15 / ""[t] -- {
16 / ""[t] -- {
17 / ""[t] -- {
18 / ""[t] -- {
19 / ""[t] -- {
20 / ""[t] -- {
21 / ""[t] -- {
22 / ""[t] -- {
23 / ""[t] -- {
24 / ""[t] -- {
25 / ""[t] -- {
26 / ""[t] -- {
27 / ""[t] -- {
28 / ""[t] -- {
29 / ""[t] -- {
30 / ""[t] -- {
31 / ""[t] -- {
32 / ""[t] -- {
33 / ""[t] -- {
34 / ""[t] -- {
35 / ""[t] -- {
36 / ""[t] -- {
37 / ""[t] -- {
38 / ""[t] -- {
39 / ""[t] -- {
40 / ""[t] -- {
41 / ""[t] -- {
42 / ""[t] -- {
43 / ""[t] -- {
44 / ""[t] -- {
45 / ""[t] -- {
46 / ""[t] -- {
47 / ""[t] -- {
48 / ""[t] -- {
49 / ""[t] -- {
50 / ""[t] -- {
51 / ""[t] -- {
52 / ""[t] -- {
53 / ""[t] -- {
54 / ""[t] -- {
55 / ""[t] -- {
56 / ""[t] -- {
57 / ""[t] -- {
58 / ""[t] -- {
59 / ""[t] -- {
60 / ""[t] -- {
61 / ""[t] -- {
62 / ""[t] -- {
63 / ""[t] -- {
64 / ""[t] -- {
65 / ""[t] -- {
66 / ""[t] -- {
67 / ""[t] -- {
68 / ""[t] -- {
69 / ""[t] -- {
70 / ""[t] -- {
71 / ""[t] -- {
72 / ""[t] -- {
73 / ""[t] -- {
74 / ""[t] -- {
75 / ""[t] -- {
76 / ""[t] -- {
77 / ""[t] -- {
78 / ""[t] -- {
79 / ""[t] -- {
80 / ""[t] -- {
81 / ""[t] -- {
82 / ""[t] -- {
83 / ""[t] -- {
84 / ""[t] -- {
85 / ""[t] -- {
86 / ""[t] -- {
87 / ""[t] -- {
88 / ""[t] -- {
89 / ""[t] -- {
90 / ""[t] -- {
91 / ""[t] -- {
92 / ""[t] -- {
93 / ""[t] -- {
94 / ""[t] -- {
95 / ""[t] -- {
96 / ""[t] -- {
97 / ""[t] -- {
98 / ""[t] -- {
99 / ""[t] -- {
100 / ""[t] -- {
t101 / ""[t]
}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
};
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question would benefit much from providing those two examples. Or, at least the problematic one if the other one is lost.

Comment: try with luatex

Comment: luatex allows more groups `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=65535].`

Comment: @mickep I realize that. Would it be fine to post a file with thousands of lines of code?

Comment: @user443854 the site imposes a character limit and blocks the send above  30000 characters, but if it is within that it is ok to post.

Comment: note the number of nodes is not the probem, a node is a group so 10 nodes is `{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}` (simplifing a bit) but the nesting does not increase. You have `{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{........{{{`   255 deep so a deeply nested structure

Comment: @mickep and others - I added a runnable example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the maximum depth of nesting in my graph is 108.

Comment: @user443854 node nesting 108 and probably two groups per node, so already over 200 and add a few levels from a tikz  and/or figure and 255 is getting close....

Comment: @user443854 your example works in lualatex

Comment: I was intimidated by Lualatex manual, and even more so by the installation instructions. Then I realized it is supported by MikTex (which I am using). All I had to do was to change the processing tools in the settings. It works!

Comment: Is there more to this diagram than you posted? Because `a -- { b -- {c -- {…}}}` is just `a -- b -- c -- …`. Maybe we can write it differently without having to introduce so many groups.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel you are correct. The example I provided is a contrived one. The real graph has has branching, so it looks more like `a -- { b, c -- {...}, ..., y }, z }`

Answer (score 4):

The basic test file for that error is as below.
Unfortunately I don't think you can increase the limit without changing the source code of tex, despite `texmf.cnf` comment:

```
nest_size = 1000        % simultaneous semantic levels (e.g., groups)
```

In texlive 2023:

using latex or pdflatex

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
```

Using xetex, ptex or luatex:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=65535].
```

using hitex you hit save stack first.

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=100000].
```

---

```
\def\x{\bgroup\x}
\x
```